# How to create a authorization service in react?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, authentication, authorization

I have create a react application in which I have used Azure AD authentication for logging in.
Now for the part of authorization I want to create a .net api that can authorize with the help of a token that whether this person is the right one or not.

In frontend I have used ReactJS and in backend I want to use .net for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EntityFramework` with `JwtBearer` for that. You'll be able to create tokens for each session and you can put your users in a Role-based authorization access to your app.

Comment: Do you have any link for the reference where I can refer the same?

Comment: @Avanish You can look here. It will give you an idea: [link](https://rainstormtech.com/aspnet-core-identity-with-jwt-and-react)